# How to use of nloptr library to maximize Spearman correlation between two arrays

Tags: r, row, regression, nonlinear-optimization, nlopt

I have two arrays. For example the first one is A and the second B:

A<-c(2,5,6,10,11)
B<-c(13,2,6,8,12)

Also I have constant teta=1. 
I made an array :

D=B-teta

and correlation coefficient between A and D

koeff<-cor(A,D)

The challenge is make koeff the maximum value by changing constant teta. 
As I understood I can use nloptr library. How should I use use it?

Best regards!

P.S. I made this work in excel with solver general reduced gradient.I have not find this function in R.

Comment: The Spearman correlation is on ranks right? So a fixed displacement (this does not change the ranking) would not make a difference.

Comment: I am sorry,you are right.

Comment: D= log(D+teta) That was the right array

Comment: `log(x(i)+ϑ)` does not change the ranking either (it is monotonic). You may want to think a bit about the problem first.

Comment: Erwin,I made such job in excel. If teta is near -2 the correleation is growing up. I dont know how. I want to do such job by function optimisation

Comment: Is that for the above data? Note that `log(B(2)-2)` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Illustration that `log(B+ϑ)` does not change the ordering.

```
> # ranks for different theta
> theta <- -1; rank(log(B+theta))
[1] 5 1 2 3 4
> theta <- 3; rank(log(B+theta))
[1] 5 1 2 3 4
> theta <- 10; rank(log(B+theta))
[1] 5 1 2 3 4
> # theta=-2 is a border case: we get -infinity
> theta=-2; log(B+theta)
[1] 2.397895     -Inf 1.386294 1.791759 2.302585
> rank(log(B+theta))
[1] 5 1 2 3 4
>
```

As a result all Spearman correlations should be the same:

```
> A <- c(2,5,6,10,11)
> cor(A,B,method="spearman")
[1] 0
> theta <- -1; cor(A,log(B+theta),method="spearman")
[1] 0
> theta <- 3; cor(A,log(B+theta),method="spearman")
[1] 0
> theta <- 10; cor(A,log(B+theta),method="spearman")
[1] 0
> theta <- -2; cor(A,log(B+theta),method="spearman")
[1] 0
>
```